# Regex optionally choose anything or anything inside quotes

Tags: regex

I have the following cases,

```
docId:1234
docName:"Document"
docDescription:"Document description"
```

I want to use regex to extract the key and value in the above cases.

I generated `(.+?):\"(.*)\"`. 
group1 -> docName, group2 -> Document

But this worked only for the 2nd and 3rd cases. 
I tried something like `(.+?):\"(.*)\"|(.*)`. But they provide me with the wrong results. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: [`^([^:]*):(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/xB9xF1/1)

Comment: What is the regex flavor / programming language? You should have grouped the alternatives: [`(.+?):(?:\"(.*)\"|(.*))`](https://regex101.com/r/zP3tI7/1). But there can be better solutions.

Comment: The simple solution for you i believe is to make the quotes optional - `(.+?):"?(.*)"?`. (The don't need to be quoted for the regex - they might need to be by your environment thought...)

Comment: @Tushar it works. but they display the double quotes also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with optional back-reference matching:

```
([^:]+):("?)([^"]+)\2
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iO9qS0/1)

`\2` is back-reference for optional `"` after colon.

Answer (score 0):

use this, it returns key and value respectively:

```
^(\w+):\"?(.*)\"?$
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/gX1aX8/1